# Build levmar.h library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries, lapack, nmake

I need to develop a [program](https://github.com/MPaggiaro/thesis/blob/master/HestonCalibrator.cpp) in C++ which uses the function `dlevmar_der` (line 646) of the `levmar` library, implemented by [Lourakis](http://users.ics.forth.gr/%7Elourakis/levmar/index.html).

I followed the steps explained in this interesting [blog](https://uglyduckling.nl/blog/financial-engineering/compiling-levmar-using-nmake-visual-studio-2010/). I was able to modify the `MakeFile.vc` ([code here](https://github.com/MPaggiaro/thesis/blob/master/Makefile.vc)) to fit it to my specific program.

The problem is the following: *it seems to work only with VS2012*, but **NOT with newer versions** (e.g. VS2019).
Indeed, when I try to build the code many errors of this type occur:

```
levmar.lib(Axb.obj) : error LNK2019: reference to external symbol _dgeqrf_ not solved in function _dAx_eq_b_QR
```

Since I need `levmar` library only for one function, I don't understand why I need to include and use all the libraries coming from `lapack` as well, as I do in `MakeFile.vc`:

```
LIBOBJS=lm.obj Axb.obj misc.obj lmlec.obj lmbc.obj lmblec.obj lmbleic.obj
LIBSRCS=lm.c Axb.c misc.c lmlec.c lmbc.c lmblec.c lmbleic.c
DEMOBJS=HestonCalibrator.obj
DEMOSRCS=HestonCalibrator.cpp
AR=lib /nologo

# comment the following line if you are not using LAPACK
LAPACKLIBS= clapack.lib blas.lib BLAS_nowrap.lib libf2c.lib
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a simpler way to build `levmar` and run the code?
2. Do I really need to use MakeFiles and include in the path all these other libraries?

Thank you in advance!